# How can I cut an image into several pieces ? (REACT NATIVE)

Tags: react-native, image, expo, puzzle

I wanna make a puzzle and I need to cut an image. I use expo workflow. Is there any library for cut or divide an image?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at these packages

1. https://github.com/guhungry/react-native-photo-manipulator/blob/master/README.md#crop-and-resize
2. https://github.com/callstack/react-native-image-editor
3. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mtourj/react-native-image-crop

Comment: First of all thanks for sharing, but I do not need to crop an image.I am looking for divide or cut into several pieces.

Comment: Maybe you can manipulate crop function for android and ios files